# Android studio - ndk_build_command failing on Clean task

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I recently checked out a project originally built under Windows (using JNI) in my Studio on Ubuntu

When I run a clean task, I see an error when it tries to execute what seems to be a Windows ndk-clean command

```
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:UsersTishuAppDataLocalAndroidandroid-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64android-ndk-r8endk-build.cmd
```

I am not sure what triggers this command but it happens on this task: 'externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'

I have searched in my project for references to 'AppData' and found few in this file: project/.externalNativeBuilds/ndkbuild/debug/mips/ndkBuild_build_commands.txt

This file contains windows related information, starting with

```
Executable : C:\Users\Tishu\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd
```

Problem is I cannot find this file in Files or in Studio. The .externalNativeBuilds folder doesn't show. I have this is my build.gradle

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

And the Android.mk file contains only

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=false
LOCAL_MODULE := jpgexif
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JpgExif.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How do I disable this step, or update it to be relevant for my platform?

Comment: can't you update this: `C:\Users\Tishu\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64` to point to your NDK location on Ubuntu?

Comment: I would but I cannot find the file at all. It appears in the search but not when I browse the project. The .externalNativeBuilds folder doesnt show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like either of these things have happened:

1. Someone checked the `.externalNativeBuild` directory into the repo, which they shouldn't have done. The build tools should generate that directory for you locally. If you can't see the directory in the file explorer, press `Ctrl+H`, or whatever the command is to show hidden files. Then delete the directory and trigger a gradle sync. Or just remove it from a terminal window.
2. Someone checked the `local.properties` file into the repo, and in it they set the `ndk.dir` property to a Windows path. Again, this file should probably not be part of your shared repository. If this is what happened you might be able to fix it by editing the file and specifying the correct NDK path for your machine, and then triggering a gradle sync.

Comment: Yep. This was exactly the solution in my case; I had inadvertently checked in to the repo some of those build files.